# Solr on Websphere 8.5.5 : Linkage Error with org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Tags: java, solr, websphere-8, linkageerror

```
I am installing solr ( 4.10.2 ) on WAS 8.5.5 with IBM jdk 7. <br>
I deployed the `solr` as a `war` and added `solr.data.dir` and `solr.solr.home` to the application custom properties.
<br>
Upon accessing the url: http://localhost:9080/solr, <br>
I see the 'Linkage Error' in the logs.
```

> ```
> 4/03/15 06:50:58:277 GMT] 000000ae webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter (initialization failure)
>     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:176)
>     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1600)
> ..........................<br>
> ...........................<br>
> used by: **java.lang.LinkageError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory**
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
>     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
> ```

I modified the  `lib` of the downloaded `solr.war`.  On the top of the jars already present in the `solr.war/WEB-INF/lib`, I added an additional set of jars from the `downloaded solr package`

- All the jars from \solr-4.10.2\solr-4.10.2\dist
  [image]
- All the jars from \solr-4.10.2\solr-4.10.2\dist\solrj-lib
  [image]
- All the jars from \solr-4.10.2\solr-4.10.2\example\lib\ext
  [image]
- Modified the application Class Loading to 'PARENT_LAST'.

  Have been scratching my head for over 16 hours. 
  Even tried removing the `all the slf4j*.jars from the solr.war\WEB-INF\lib` but the same error persists.

Some help is highly solicited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to make SOLR up and running on Websphere 8.5.5

I have enumerated the different steps on my blog.

[Solr 4.10.2 Deployment on WebSphere855](http://was8.blogspot.in/2015/03/solr-4102-deployment-on-websphere-855.html)

Comment: Starting from Solr 5, configurations other than built-in Jetty are not supported. Something to keep in mind before you get really locked into WAS.

Comment: Oh yes. Just saw the release notes. Thank you sharing !